# Visual Studio 2008 web site with files with no Advanced properties showing

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have to get at the build action in advanced properties for some nhibernate .hbm.xml files. This web site does not show the advanced group for any files in the web site.

It is a version 2.0 site which I am editing with a VS2008 which is .net 3.5. I don't know if that is the issue or if the site just does not have a VS project defined or what.

Other sites I have created in VS2008 show that property group.  What can be done to get those, see those or enable those in this site?

Comment: I have narrowed it down to the difference between opening this as a website and creating an asp .net project and moving the site into the project. Then the advanced tab on properties appears but I have referential problems resolving references to things like vb files in my  APP_Code directory. and various links between aspx pages and their associated .vb files.  Seems like this should not be that hard.

Answer (score 0):

The advanced properties do not show up when the file itself has focus (i.e. is being edited in the text editor), but they will show up when the file is selected in the Solution Explorer (and the Solution Explorer has focus).

To select the currently-being-edited file in the Solution Explorer, you can use the shortcut Ctrl+Alt+L.

I'm not sure if this was your problem or not.